# How to position multiple images vertically on the top of a single image

Tags: html, css, image

I am positioning multiple images (one below other) on the top of a single image .
The number of images to be placed on the top is coming from back-end, so css that I applied to position one image on other is working only for one image and not for other images.
How to do so? Since I am getting only one image at the top . Basically three foreground images need to position vertically on one backgroundimage.

```
<div class="row">
{% for a in count %}
  <div class="column">
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='building.jpg') }}" id="backgroundimage" title="Total Floors: 3&#10;Total Rooms: 6" />
      <p>{{ a }}</p>
    {% for b in rows%}
     <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='building.jpg') }}" id="foregroundimage" title="Total Floors: 3&#10;Total Rooms: 6" />
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try covering the images in seperate divs with same class name.

Comment: I tried that but all the foreground images are being placed on the top of each other and not one below other

Comment: Let me know if it work. I can't currently test it as my working envirorment won't allow it so if you get an error let share the error.

Comment: No, since i have more than one image that is being displayed through same loop, so i can't put them under different divs

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are trying to do, I would play with the CSS z-index value,
with the help of Jinja2 **loop.index** function.

> So try this:

```
<div class="row">
{% for a in count %}
  <div class="column">
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='building.jpg') }}" id="backgroundimage" title="Total Floors: 3&#10;Total Rooms: 6" />
      <p>{{ a }}</p>
    {% for b in rows%}
     <img style="z-index: -{{loop.index}};" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='building.jpg') }}" id="foregroundimage" title="Total Floors: 3&#10;Total Rooms: 6" />
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Worth to note.

### loop.index

- The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)

### loop.index0

- The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)

> [CSS z-index Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

> [Jinja2 For Variables](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for)